# How would I make my edges look like this?

Tags: edges

So I was looking through models on a Discord server, and I stumbled across this picture.
[image]

While looking at the picture I wanted to see how I would make my edges look like that in the picture, as if they where white. I tried searching everywhere and couldn't find it, I think this is a Matcap but I could not find it on my Blender version.
If anybody can show me how to do make my edges look like this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is pretty much easily done in this section of Blender:
[image]

Just check Cavity, give Ridge higher number and try to change those settings. It will simply highlight your edges better, you can even give it shadows and set many different things... Try it and you will get it (Also don't forget your object must look similar to get similar look